# box resizes when zoom

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm having some troubles with box i created.
I don't know how to prevent box from resizing when i zoom in or out.
This is really bothering me since this makes my avatar not fit in.

Picture:

[image]

code:

```
<div class="header-profile">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="profile-picture-position">
            <img src="/blog/uploads/',$_SESSION['avatar'],'" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="160" height="160"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.header-profile
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 22%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: #1DA1F2 !important
}
```

container is bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your box is staying at the same size. It's the header div that gets resized because it covers %22 of the height even if you zoom in or out. You can

1) make box size relative too.

2) make header div size absolute

to fix their proportion when the page is zoomed in or out.

Comment: Tried it with this 
.header-profile
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 22%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: #1DA1F2 !important
}

but its not working

Comment: No, What I meant is make something like "height: 50px" not relative. I said one way is make box size relative not the header position.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced height with 240px and it works :)